# Quotient by equivalence relation

Tags: matrices

Let $E=\{M\in \mathbb Z^{2\times 2}\mid \det M=2\}$. 
Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $E$ by :
$$A\sim B\iff \exists U,V\in \rm{SL_2(\Bbb Z)} : \left\{\begin{align*}A=BU\\A=VB\end{align*}\right.$$
(It is similar to "being associated in divisibility" in an integral domain)

How can we describe the quotient $E\,  / \sim $ ? Is the set of equivalence classes finite or infinite ? What could be a set of representatives ?

Comment: There are no $M$ and $N$ on the right side of this "definition".

Comment: It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

So, $A$ and $B$ are equivalent iff they are both "left-equivalent"
and "right-equivalent". Now $A$ and $B$ are left equivalent ($A=VB$
with $V\in\text{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$) iff they have the same "row-space"
(lattice spanned by their rows). This lattice has index $2$ in $\Bbb Z^2$;
there are three such lattices.

Likewise $A$ and $B$ are right equivalent iff they have the same column space. So $A\sim B$ iff they have the same row and column spaces
and there are at most $3\times 3=9$ equivalence classes. I see no
reason why any given combination or row and column spaces cannot occur...